# Convert weekly dates to monthly week data using Stata

Tags: date, stata

I have a `%tw` date format variable in Stata. I want to generate a monthly week variable. Like in the example below, the variable Date2 has 1999w14 now I want to generate 1999mayw1 in Stata. How can I approach this

```
Date2   date2
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w14 1999mayw1
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
1999w15 1999mayw2
```

Comment: No attempt at code or signs of any research.

Answer (score 1):

Stata has no concept of the first week in a given month. How could it? Weeks don't map neatly on to months, or even vice versa, unless you are talking about February in non-leap years which has exactly 4 weeks, but starting on different days in different years.

If you have some particular concept of a week, e.g. that it starts on Monday, then tell us what it is.

Stata week 1 always starts on 1 January, 2 on 8 January, and so forth, and week 52 always has either 8 or 9 days. If your data match those definitions, fine. Otherwise you may need to do some reading to work out what matches your problem.

If you issue the command below in Stata, you will get clickable links to .pdf versions.

```
. search week, sj

Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, SJs, and STBs

SJ-12-4 dm0065_1  . . . . . Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks, erratum
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/12   SJ 12(4):765                                     (no commands)
        lists previously omitted key reference

SJ-12-3 dm0065  . . . . . . . . . .  Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q3/12   SJ 12(3):565--569                                (no commands)
        discusses how to convert data presented in yearly and weekly
        form to daily dates and how to aggregate such data to months
        or longer intervals

SJ-10-4 dm0052  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Stata tip 68: Week assumptions
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/10   SJ 10(4):682--685                                (no commands)
        tip on Stata's solution for weeks and on how to set up
        your own alternatives given different definitions of the
        week
```

That said, if you're content to take your data as Stata weeks, you can convert to months and label as you wish. This script requires that you download `labmask` from the *Stata Journal* site (start with `search labmask, sj`).

```
clear 
set obs 10 
gen wdate = yw(1999, _n) 
format wdate %tw  
list 

gen mdate = mofd(dofw(wdate)) 
format mdate %tm 
bysort mdate (wdate) : gen week = _n 

gen label = string(mdate, "%tm") + "w" + string(week) 

clonevar wdate2 = wdate

* install from Stata Journal site after -search labmask- 
labmask wdate2, values(label) 

list, sepby(mdate)  

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |   wdate    mdate   week      label     wdate2 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1999w1   1999m1      1   1999m1w1   1999m1w1 |
  2. |  1999w2   1999m1      2   1999m1w2   1999m1w2 |
  3. |  1999w3   1999m1      3   1999m1w3   1999m1w3 |
  4. |  1999w4   1999m1      4   1999m1w4   1999m1w4 |
  5. |  1999w5   1999m1      5   1999m1w5   1999m1w5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  6. |  1999w6   1999m2      1   1999m2w1   1999m2w1 |
  7. |  1999w7   1999m2      2   1999m2w2   1999m2w2 |
  8. |  1999w8   1999m2      3   1999m2w3   1999m2w3 |
  9. |  1999w9   1999m2      4   1999m2w4   1999m2w4 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
 10. | 1999w10   1999m3      1   1999m3w1   1999m3w1 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: So, downvoter, do please explain what's wrong with this or your better idea.